# How to add one column from one csv to another csv through python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have 2 csv files and want to copy the column from score.csv to marklist.csv as 3rd column. Every 1 hrs score.csv file will get update and those column should be added as new column(4th column, 5th column) in marklist.csv

Python version - 2.7

**marklist.csv**

```
name,subject
angel,maths
mark,science
krish,social
```

**score.csv**

```
score
70
80
85
```

I have tried with below code but it was replacing the existing marklist.csv content itself.Please guide how to do this.

```
import csv    
with open('score.csv', 'r') as readFile:
    reader = csv.reader(readFile)
    lines = list(reader)

with open('marklist.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    writer.writerows(lines)

readFile.close()
writeFile.close()
```

**Actual ouptut**

```
marklist.csv
score
70
80
85
```

**Expected output**

```
marklist.csv
name,subject,score
angel,maths,70
mark,science,80
krish,social,85
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
import csv

with open('score.csv', 'r') as score, open('marklist.csv', 'r') as marklist, \
    open('result.csv', 'w') as result:
    score_reader = csv.reader(score)
    marklist_reader = csv.reader(marklist)
    result = csv.writer(result)
    result.writerows(x + y for x, y in zip(marklist_reader, score_reader))
```